# Extract weblink from webpage using excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i am having a set of web link in excel and i need to update a new web link.
It is difficult to open every web link and getting a new link for reference. I heard of VBA but i am not well known in VBA.

i have add a sample web link and sample image from i need to scrape the link to excel.

in---->sheet 1------> Column A ---> 100+ web links are having. for every weblink a new web link is needed .

Here is the sample web link--->[here](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/design/package-specifications/packageDetails.html?id=PN_NBGAF-042).

From here under Product Specifications section there's a dimension tab. i need to retrieve the link to same sheet of excel in column B.

Can you please go through the question and and write me a script to do this?

[image]

Comment: Questions asking us to write you a script are frowned upon here.

Comment: I just need a help i am new to VBA and i dont know to how to proceed with it. If you are not willing to help out You can do your business. Its an social media any one can ask what they had a doubt.

Comment: We're not code writers.